# How to download response file react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I download the document I receive in return?

Here are the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control: public
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reserve_list_1998_02_02.odt
Content-Length: 3621
Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
```

Response:
[image]

I am trying to do like this:

```
<Link to={printDoc} download>DOWNLOAD</Link> // printDoc - my response (picture up)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you've already downloaded the file. That's what all that gobbledygook is. You just need to assign the attachment from the response into your printDoc variable, I think.